# Vuejs - How to send data from one component to another to switch beteween pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vue-component, parent-child

I have wizard setup vuejs web app. It's single page form app.
There are 3 vue components:
Starter.vue
Selection1.vue
Selection2.vue

When I am at Selection1 or 2. If I clicked to Back button, I'll be returned to Starter.vue ' s First page. It has to be last page of Starter.vue

Starter Component:

I have my own paging system in one component which they are in `mounted()`;

```
...
mounted() {
$(".back-btn").click(function () {
        var active = $(".wizard-form").children(".slide-active");
        var id = active.attr("for");
        active.removeClass("slide-active");
        id = parseInt(id);
        id--;
        $(".slide-" + id).addClass("slide-active");
      });
    
      $(".next-btn").click(function () {
        var active = $(".wizard-form").children(".slide-active");
        var id = active.attr("for");
        active.removeClass("slide-active");
        id = parseInt(id);
        id++;
        $(".slide-" + id).addClass("slide-active");
      });
},
...
```

Those are the my main `div` 's for paging

```
<form class="form-slide" @submit.prevent="submitFormWizard">
    <div class="slide-element slide-active slide-1" for="1">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="slide-element slide-2" for="2">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="slide-element slide-3" for="3">
     ...
              <router-link v-show="select_op==='selection1'" to="/selection1">
                <button type="button">Go 1</button>
              </router-link>
              <router-link v-show="select_op==='selection2'" to="/selection2">
                <button type="button">Go 2</button>
              </router-link>
              
              <button class="back-btn type="button"> Back </button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

Other components (selection 1 and selection 2) which they are in `<router-link>` 's ;

```
<template>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div>
       <form class="form-slide">
         <div class="slide-element slide-active slide-1" for="1">
          ...
          <router-link to="/wizard/startup">
            <button type="button"> Back </button>
          </router-link>

          <button  type="button"> Next </button>
         
        </div>
        ...
        ...
    </section>
  </main>
</template>
```

Here is the deal; When I went to Selection 2 or 1. And press Back button. It returns to first page of Starter Component, It has to be Third page. How can I make this right ?
(props does not work I have tried.)